# Wait for Navigator.pop animation

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

Currently, I have a seperate page to view a specific entity.
On the seperate page, users may delete this entity.
To make the code more "clean", I want to first pop this separate page and then delete the entity from the list. However, I cannot delete it right away because there is a short time frame where the page still exists. My workaround is to add a delay to make sure that the page is "disposed". Is there a cleaner way?

```dart
onTap: () async {
    final result = await Navigator.push<MyPageResult>(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => MyEntityPage(id: id),
    );

    if (result == MyPageResult.delete) {
        // wait for page to be correctly disposed (animation to be finished)
        // this is the dirty approach, is there a cleaner way?
        await sleepAsync(1000);
        ref.read(dataProvider.notifier).deleteEntity(id: id);
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get if you comment `await sleepAsync(1000);` ?

Comment: Try once with a then method after the navigation.

Comment: @tien-do-nam Have you found a better solution for this?